# Accessing Variable from nested loops

Tags: django, python-3.x

I need to access variable from a nested loop in django, but I got empty data instead

Here is the piece of code

```
def connections(request):
     """get service connections from api"""
     brand_res = requests.get(url+'?method=api.brand_list',
                         auth=HTTPBasicAuth(name, token))
     brands = brand_res.json()
     for key, brand in brands['data'].items():
       services = []
       service_plans = requests.get(
        url+'?method=api.service_plan_list&code=SDNCCNNIRTTTT&brand_id='+brand['class_id'], auth=HTTPBasicAuth(name, token))
     plans = service_plans.json()
       if isinstance(plans['data'], dict):
         """if dict"""
         for m, plan in plans['data'].items():
            """ get all plan_ids"""
            services_connected = requests.get(
                url+'?method=client.service_list&plan_id=' + plan['plan_id'], auth=HTTPBasicAuth(name, token))
            sho = services_connected.json()
            services.append(sho)

       else:
         """if list"""
         for plan in plans:
            print('')
            print('')
            print('')

return HttpResponse(services)
```

But I have no luck in returning the data to pass in html as json

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your method? Where exactly is your "empty data"?

Comment: printing sho(print(sho)) contains data from api, the problem is when accessing that variable out side loop, the original value of services variable which is empty is being called in HttpResponse(services)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly - before you do `services.append(sho)` you do a `print(sho)` which contains data. Before you do `return HttpResponse(services)` you do a `print(services)` and this one is empty?

Comment: printing service after services.append(sho) still contains data if inside loop

Comment: I can confirm printing services outs contains no data,

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `services = []`  at the beginning of each loop - is that correct? Why you don't initiate that before the loop?